# Why do we have to create unique uuid for every interface in a idl?

Tags: com, uuid, idl

Why do we have to create unique `uuid` for each interface in a  idl ?

For example in this interface there's a unique uuid for every interface in `TradingLib`.

```
import "oaidl.idl";

[uuid(7C948DDC-8C22-46CF-91AD-1E043A0E1A10), object]
interface IInventory : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT GetStock([out, retval] long* pStock);
    HRESULT Buy([in] long quantity, [in] float rate);
    HRESULT Sell([in] long quantity, [in] float rate);
};

[uuid(F7CF450D-C4BE-4943-A384-AA5BB4A89202), object]
interface IAccount : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT GetBalance([out, retval] double* pBalance);
    HRESULT Credit([in] double amount);
    HRESULT Debit([in] double amount);
};

[uuid(9791C352-4665-403C-8A37-3EC8485A87D5), version(1.0), helpstring("XYZ Trading Library")]
library TradingLib
{
    importlib("stdole32.tlb");

    [uuid(03698856-A173-417F-93CF-AEBC27EB042A)]
    coclass Trader
    {
        [default] interface IInventory;
        interface IAccount;
    };

    [uuid(E596BE02-0DCE-4B7C-B8D4-4F621F675BF0)]
    enum TradingErrors
    {
        TRADER_E_OUTOFSTOCK = 0x80040101,
        TRADER_E_INSUFFICIENTFUNDS = 0x80040102
    };
};
```

Why can't we just use a single uuid for the `TradingLib` library itself? Why is it necessary to create `uuid` for every interface?

Thanks.

Comment: It is equivalent to asking "why do I have to give classes in my program a distinct name?"  The guid of an interface is the name, the identifier you use is only for your convenience but doesn't get used by COM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each COM interface must have a unique id associated with it. Each time you introduce a new interface you have to assign it a new unique id.

That's one of COM conventions - if you know an interface id you know what the interface is (all it's method with exact signatures). So in your example the answer is - you can't reuse an id because each distinct interface must have its own unique id.

Answer (score 3):

when you ask for an instance of a com object, you usually do it using a method called 
`CreateInstance`, and then call `QueryInterface` on that instace to get a reference to the  specific interface on that object that you need.
`QueryInterface` takes a uuid as a parameter. so you cant use the same guid for 
two distict interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows the UUID is used in the registry as the node name where the interface is registered as existing. There might be more reasons but this is one place where it is used.

Comment: That's the question, why can't  COM just register the dll instead of registering each interface? The interface then can be found by QueryInterface method, this confuses me a lot.

Comment: the thing is , COM is all about abstracting away implementation from contract. so the interfaces are unique and immutable. the library isnt the main entity here.

Comment: @Searock The Interface is not owned by the library so the name of an interface is not enough to identify it. UUID is unique enough to identify a Interface.

Comment: @Searock Ruzario: Well, technically you could reuse an interface if you didn't use idl and it would work in most scenarios, but it's bad practice. The convention is you give each interface a unique id and MIDL enforces that on you.